# Mass file copy to domain computers

Tags: powershell, unc

I am trying to take a screen saver file I've made and copy it to all of our desktops and laptops \system32 folder. I created a computers text file and found this script, but I keep getting this error. Any help would be appreciated.

Running this in Powershell 3.0 on a 2012 Server logged in as an admin.

```
$computers = gc "\\server\share\scripts\computers.txt"
$source = "\\share\scripts\MySlideshow.scr"
$dest = "C:\Windows\System32"
foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    if (test-Connection -Cn $computer -quiet) {
        Copy-Item $source -Destination \\$computer\$dest -Recurse
    } else {
        "$computer is not online"
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Copy-Item : The given path's format is not supported.
At C:\users\tech\desktop\scripts\screen.ps1:6 char:9
+         Copy-Item $source -Destination \\$computer\$dest -Recurse
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NotSupportedException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

Comment: shouldn't that be `$source = '\\server01\share\scripts\MySlideshow.scr'`?

Comment: `\\$computer\$dest` won't work, because it isn't a valid pathname. (If the computer is `\\Test`, it would result in `\\Test\C:\Windows\System32`, which is illegal. You can't have an embedded `:` in a UNC pathname.)

Answer (score 2):

The resulting UNC format for you destination is invalid. You're passing

```
"\\computer\c:\windows\system32"
```

when you should be passing

```
"\\computer\c$\windows\system32"
```

Try quoting the `-destination` parameter like this too:

```
Copy-Item $source -Destination "\\$computer\$dest" -Recurse
```

You'll also need to use single-quotes when assigning to `$dest` to prevent powershell from trying to expand the dollar sign as a variable sigil.

```
$dest = 'c$\windows\system32'
```

Debug your script by using `copy-item -whatif ...` to ensure that you're passing the correct parameters.